# Regex to match all characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text input field in which a user can enter some text. Starting with 1 character, I want to match all elements containing that character.

Elements: (array: messages)

- Hi
- Hello
- Good
- Dog

When I enter 'H', the first 2 elements should match.

When I enter 'E', the second element should match.

When I enter 'HI', the first element should match.

And so on...

Anyway, I want to match ALL characters. When I enter a letter or a number it works, but when I enter a parenthesis, I get the following error:
**Invalid regular expression: unmatched parentheses**

My regex:

```
messages.filter(e => e.match(new RegExp(filterQuery, 'i')))
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/153691/escape-user-input-for-use-in-js-regex

Answer (score -1):

```
var txt ="h";
var reg = new RegExp(txt,'i');
var filterarr= arr.filter(e => reg.exec(e));
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Regex to match all characters in javascript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Array: <div id="div"></div>
        <br />
        Filter Array: <div id="divfilter"></div>
        <script>
         var arr = ["Hi","Hello","Good","Dog"];
         
        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = getString(arr);
        
     var txt ="h";
     var reg = new RegExp(txt,'i');
         var filterarr= arr.filter(e => reg.exec(e));
         
         document.getElementById("divfilter").innerHTML = getString(filterarr);
            
        function getString(arr){
            var str="";
            for(let i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
             if(i!=0)
                str+=", ";
             str += arr[i];
            }
            return str;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```